# AngularDart - How to replace a component in AppLayout

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, angular-components, angular-dart-routing

I want to replace `component-a` from `component-b` and `component-c` while on click on `material-navigation` item inside `material-content` of App Layout.

app_layout_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/material_persistent_drawer.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/content/deferred_content.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_button/material_button.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_icon/material_icon.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list_item.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_toggle/material_toggle.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'app-layout',
    directives: const [
      DeferredContentDirective,
      MaterialButtonComponent,
      MaterialIconComponent,
      MaterialListComponent,
      MaterialListItemComponent,
      MaterialPersistentDrawerDirective,
      MaterialToggleComponent,

    ],
    templateUrl: 'app_layout_component.html',
    styleUrls: const [
      'app_layout_component.css',
      'package:angular_components/app_layout/layout.scss.css',
    ])
class AppLayoutComponent {
  bool end = false;
}
```

app_component.html

```
<material-drawer persistent #drawer="drawer" [attr.end]="end ? '' : null">
  <material-list *deferredContent>
    <div group class="mat-drawer-spacer"></div>
    <div group>
      <material-list-item>
        <material-icon icon="inbox"></material-icon>Inbox
      </material-list-item>
      <material-list-item>
        <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Star
      </material-list-item>
      <material-list-item>
        <material-icon icon="send"></material-icon>Sent Mail
      </material-list-item>
      <material-list-item>
        <material-icon icon="drafts"></material-icon>Drafts
      </material-list-item>
    </div>
    <div group>
      <div label>Tags</div>
      <material-list-item>
        <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Favorites
      </material-list-item>
    </div>
  </material-list>
</material-drawer>
<material-content>
  <header class="material-header shadow">
    <div class="material-header-row">
      <material-button icon
                       class="material-drawer-button" (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
        <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
      </material-button>
      <span class="material-header-title">Simple Layout</span>
      <div class="material-spacer"></div>
      <nav class="material-navigation">
        <a href="#AppLayout">Link 1</a>
      </nav>
      <nav class="material-navigation">
        <a href="#AppLayout">Link 2</a>
      </nav>
      <nav class="material-navigation">
        <a href="#AppLayout">Link 3</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <component-a></component-a>

</material-content>
```

Comment: I would do that using routing https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial/toh-pt5, see also https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/tree/master/angular_router and https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/master/angular_router/g3doc/migration_guide.md

Comment: I am already doing it with `angular_router` but how to include app layout in all the component. Do I need to write the drawer and header code in each component.

Comment: No, you'd replace `<component-a></component-a>` with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and the router would replace it with `<component-a></component-a>`, `<component-b></component-b>`, `<component-c></component-c>` depending on the active route. You can then create links to navigate from one route to the other (or do it in code). Another advantage is that the browser URL-bar reflects the status (what the active route is).

Comment: What Angular version are you using?

Comment: `dependencies:
  angular: "^4.0.0+2"`

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options:

- use `NgIf`s to control which widget shows based on some condition - this is nice if you have two or maybe three standard widgets
- use [DynamicComponent](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/lib/dynamic_component/dynamic_component.dart) if your clients need to display any components - then you can just pass the *ComponentFactory for any widget
- use [Router](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial/toh-pt5) if you have more well defined components and want the state to be easily reflected in the URL.